# Conditionally ignore case in c++11 regular expressions

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to write a function which will allow the user to specify if they want to ignore case in a regular expression match.  I've come up with a solution, but it's pretty clunky. Is there a way to conditionally set the `std::regex_constants::icase` flag when building the regex?

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>

std::string sub(std::string string, std::string match, bool ic){
  std::regex r;
  std::regex rc(match, std::regex_constants::collate);
  std::regex ric(match, std::regex_constants::icase | std::regex_constants::collate);
  if(ic){
    r = ric;
  } else {
    r = rc;
  }
  std::smatch matches;
  if(std::regex_search(string,matches, r)){
    return matches[0];
  } else {
    return "no match";
  }
}
```

Comment: something like `auto flags = collate | (ic ? icase : 0);` perhaps?

Comment: @vu1p3n0x would that be a line and then pass in like `std::regex r(match,flags)`?

Comment: On a side note, your function should have parameters that are reference to const objects: `std::string sub(std::string const& string, std::string const& match, bool ic)` to avoid useless copying of arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to conditionally set the flag. For example using the conditional operator:

```
std::regex r(match, ic ? std::regex_constants::icase | std::regex_constants::collate
    : std::regex_constants::collate);
```

Comment: I understand this could just be a compiler issue, but in case it isn't.  When I try to compile my function with your code, I get an error, `no matching function for call to 'std::basic_regex<char>::basic_regex(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >::value_type&, unsigned int)'` I was able to create a solution that worked for me based on using the conditional operator, though, so thanks!

Comment: Ah, the joys of "beware, I only proved it correct, I didn't run it" ;-)

Comment: All I did was list both flags on the 'TRUE' side and only collate on the 'FALSE' side. don't know if that's bad for other reasons, but it worked!

Answer (score 1):

In such cases I prefer good old `if` for readability:

```
auto flags = std::regex_constants::collate;
if(ic) flags |= std::regex_constants::icase;
std::regex r(match, flags);
```

This code will also be easier to maintain than a version with conditional operator `?`.
Consider that you want to add another conditional flag in the future. It's a simple as adding another `if` line:

```
if(ns) flags |= std::regex_constants::nosubs;
```

Try to do this with conditional operator and the code will quickly degrade into spaghetti.